# Use Java keystore to hold self-certified cert, export cert as x509 .cer file sans private key, obtain private key in my Java program to sign stuff

Tags: java, security, encryption, keystore

As I understand it, if I do:

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias foo
```

it creates, in one step, certificate, a private key, and a public key.

That's great.  Now I can export the public portions of the certificate (the information about the subject of the certificate, and the public key), in a 'Privacy Enhanced Mail' (PEM) format as per RFC 1421 by doing:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias foo -rfc > mycert.cer
```

I can now give `mycert.cer` to the party that needs to verify signatures I generate with the private key.  That private key remains private in the keystore (both the key and the store can be encrypted with a passphrase).

Finally, it just remains to obtain the private key from the keystore at runtime in my program so that I can sign stuff such that the other party can verify I signed it.

The guts of that (relying on the [KeyStore doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html) as cheered along by [Dr Heron Yang](http://www.herongyang.com/Cryptography/keytool-Export-Key-Dump-Private-Key.html)) is:

```
// load the keystore, supplying the store password
KeyStore jks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
jks.load(new FileInputStream(jksFile), jksPass);

// get the 'entry'
KeyStore.ProtectionParameter protParam = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(password);
KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry pkEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry)
    ks.getEntry("foo", protParam);

// grab the bits from the private key
PrivateKey myPrivateKey = pkEntry.getPrivateKey();
```

Now I could hand `myPrivateKey` (assuming it was the right sort of key, of course), to something like:

```
  // import java.security.*
  Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
  sig.initSign(myPrivateKey);
  sig.update(mybytes);
  return sig.sign();
```

and I thus generate a signature which my other party (assuming they trust the certificate I supplied them before and can associate it with stuff I send them) can use to verify that it was really me who gave them the data.

(Yes, I glossed over key types generating the cert with keytool earlier).

**Is this how it is done?**  So many other examples are extraordinarily zealous to get the certificate *and* the private key *out* of the java keystore so they can:

- paste the plain-text of the private key into their code (in PEM format)
- include the plain-text of the private key (in PEM format) as a file to be checked-in to the source code repository
- otherwise publish their private key

*OR* if the developer has some kind of clue, they are now faced with the problem of *protecting* the private key, now that they've managed to get it out of the keystore!  (This is where I was before I had a lightbulb moment!).

Comment: Tell me if the title is wrong, re the x509 bit.  I meant PEM-encoded, I think.

Comment: If anyone knows of a good 'what every user of cryptography in Java needs to know' book, please leave a comment about it :-)

Comment: You'll always end up having to protect something. If it's not the private key, then it'll be the password for the key and/or keystore.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!  The above process works a charm and feels right to boot.